# Using generated express app as backend in Angular 12

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

thank you for visiting my question. i was learning web developer by myself since 2020 (i have no mentor and all of my teacher is you, guys!). my path is to be a MEAN stack.

i have learn about fundamental HTML, CSS, JS Native, Bootstrap, SCSS and currently i was learning about JS Framework (Angular) and i was learning NodeJS and simulating a simple CRUD with mongoDB (NodeJS is not using Angular, EJS instead). btw everything i do is through local machine!

i just curious how it looks like attaching NodeJS in our ng project. i have tried to integrate it but because of lack information i still fail to integrate between those two.
and can we use generated express app which is comes by using command

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

i still have doubt on how to do it correctly or if it was answered, may you refer the related article so i can learn from it? thanks in advance <3

Comment: I think you should make it clear this relates to angular universal - if you are not using angular universal please advise.

Comment: hmmmm, k ,, thanks :)